# No mapping found for swagger-resources/configuration/ui

Tags: java, spring, documentation, swagger, springfox

I am trying to configure swagger ui in non spring boot app. I have done following things.
1. Added Following dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Added Swagger Config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
//@PropertySource("classpath:/swagger.properties")
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket proposalApis(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .groupName("test")
        .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.test.abc"))
        .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/test1.*"))
        .build()
        .apiInfo(testApiInfo());
}

private ApiInfo testApiInfo() {
    ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Test APIs").description("GET POST PUT methods are supported ").version("V1").build();
    return apiInfo;
}
}
```

3. Added following mappings :

   ```
   <mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-    INF/resources/"/>
   <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-    INF/resources/webjars/"/>
   ```

I am able to access following url's

```
    /v2/api-docs
    /swagger-resources
```

But While loading swagger-ui.html UI gets loaded and on server getting following error
[image]

```
    No mapping found for /context/swagger-resources/configuration/ui in Dispatcher servlet
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Swagger version 2.3.1 in my pom.  I wonder why you have different versions for `springfox-swagger2` and `springfox-swagger-ui` artifacts?

My SwaggerConfig class looks like this.  No properties:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Autowired
    private TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPlugin() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("FooBar")
                .select()
                //Ignores controllers annotated with @CustomIgnore
                .apis(any()) //Selection by RequestHandler
                        .paths(paths()) // and by paths
                        .build()
                        .apiInfo(apiInfo()
                        );
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo("FooBar",
                "A java server based on SpringBoot",
                "1.0.0",
                null,
                "author","","");
    }

    //Here is an example where we select any api that matches one of these paths
    private Predicate<String> paths() {
        return or(
                regex("/foobar/*.*")
                );
    }
}
```

No configuration or resources for me.

The page comes right up when I hit the URL `http://localhost:8080/foobar/swagger-ui.html`

Comment: Is your app a spring boot app? looks like it. There is no additional configuration required for spring boot app but doesn't work the same for non boot application

Comment: Yes, it is a Spring Boot application.  Sorry, I missed that detail.

Comment: Nevermind. Thanks a lot difference of versions was the only issue. When changed both of them to 2.1.2 it worked.

Comment: I'm glad to help.  Good luck.

Comment: @GaneshSalunke you're better off using 2.5.0 in both versions as it has a lot of issues fixed compared to 2.1.2

Comment: Thank you, @DilipKrishnan, I'll upgrade mine to 2.5.0 as well.

Comment: Okay sure. will use the latest thanks @DilipKrishnan

Comment: can you add the imports please, where does this `regex` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Different versioning of springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui has been an issue. In some cases, like former of 2.5.0 and latter of 2.6.1 version, the integration works fine. But, if former is of 2.6.1 and latter is of 2.4.0, then the ui becomes incompatible. Hence, I suggest if both the dependencies are taken of same version by practice, then unexpected functioning of swagger can be reduced.